# How to select Random Collection view element using Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-ui-automation

Is there anyway we can select Random Collection view element form the list using Swift.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `arc4random_uniform` to select a random index in the array.

For example:

```
let array = [AnyObject]()
let randomIndex = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count))
let randomItem = array[randomIndex]
```

Comment: I don't have any array list. I have a collection view `XCUIApplication().collectionViews.staticTexts["ABC"]` from this collection view I would like to select one.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this,

```
var myString = moodArray[arc4random() % moodArray.count]
```

It will select random element from your array.

Now you have to create new array with this random value and display it in uicollection view.